# Why dosen't add tray icon on not user account?

Tags: c++, icons, tray

I want to add tray icon on background process.
BTW, if not user account (e.g. SYSTEM) to run program, not add tray icon.
If using my account, it works.
How to add tray icon by not user account to run program?

NOTIFYICONDATA nid;

```
ZeroMemory(&nid, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hWnd;
nid.uFlags =  NIF_INFO|NIF_ICON|NIF_TIP; 

    sprintf(nid.szInfoTitle, "title"); 
    sprintf(nid.szInfo, "infomation"); 
    sprintf(nid.szTip, "tip");

nid.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;

if(g_UpdaterInfo.osver == cWinXP)
{
    nid.uTimeout = 3000;
}

nid.uID = IDI_ICON;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(_AtlBaseModule.GetModuleInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));

BOOL add = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
DWORD result = GetLastError();
CString msg;
msg.Format("Tray AddIcon: %d", result);
FileLog(LOG_FILE, msg);
if(!add)
    return FALSE;

return TRUE;
```

Comment: your question is really confusing. Do you mean you want to add tray icon when your program is running as Administrator?

Comment: No. Actually, this process is windows task. The task has start, I wanna display tray icon on the created the task with the 'SYSTEM' account.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tray icon is simple:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid;

    ZeroMemory(&nid, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    nid.hWnd = NULL;//hWnd;
    nid.uFlags =  NIF_INFO|NIF_ICON|NIF_TIP; 

    sprintf_s(nid.szInfoTitle, "title"); 
    sprintf_s(nid.szInfo, "infomation"); 
    sprintf_s(nid.szTip, "tip");

    nid.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;

    //if(g_UpdaterInfo.osver == cWinXP)
    //{
    //    nid.uTimeout = 3000;
    //}
    nid.uTimeout = 3000;

    nid.uID = IDI_ICON1;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));

    BOOL add = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
    //DWORD result = GetLastError();
    //CString msg;
    //msg.Format("Tray AddIcon: %d", result);
    //FileLog(LOG_FILE, msg);
    if(!add)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I modified the add tray icon your guide that dosen't work yet.

Comment: Hi MSalters, Yes, it's different. (SYSTEM vs my login account)

Comment: @andwella: I don't doubt that you did; I doubt that Brent81 tried with his code.

Answer (score 0):

This probably did work on XP, but stopped working on Vista?

The culprit is fairly easy. Simply said, each account has its own desktop. (Technically, it's each login session). They're separated, intentionally.

The normal solution is to have a separate command&control process to provide the entire UI. It runs under a user account and therefore can show UI in the correct desktop.

Comment: I'm working on windows 7. And the account is 'SYSTEM'. The SYSTEM account is disable windows login. Isn't it? So I don't check.

Comment: @andwella: 7 uses the same desktop architecture as Vista. `SYSTEM` of course doesn't have its own interactive login session, but that doesn't mean that it can hijack other login sessions. "Checking" wouldn't remove the problem.